# SliderTheme Breaks after Flutter upgrade to 1.19.0-0.0.pre

Tags: flutter, slider

Here's the code:

```
 Widget getSlider(BuildContext context) {
   return SliderTheme(
     data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
       overlayShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 25.0),
       trackHeight: 0,
       thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 25.0),
       thumbColor: thumbColor,
    ),
    child: Slider(
      value: value,
      min: minValue,
      max: maxValue,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      onChangeEnd: onChangeEnd,
    ),
  );
}
```

Everything seems to work fine. But after I upgraded my Flutter to version 1.19.0-0.0.pre, it breaks and give me this error:

```
 ════════ Exception caught by rendering library 
 The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during paint():
 The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: isEmpty

 The relevant error-causing widget was: 
 Slider file:///s_app/lib/components/ui_components/slider_components.dart:254:14
  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
  #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
  #1      RoundSliderThumbShape.paint (package:flutter/src/material/slider_theme.dart:2373:30)
  #2      _RenderSlider.paint (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:1323:33)
  #3      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2264:7)
  #4      PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:184:13)
  ...
  The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderSlider#4d553
  ...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=270.0, 0.0<=h<=30.0)
  ...  semantic boundary
  ...  size: Size(270.0, 30.0)
  RenderObject: _RenderSlider#4d553
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=270.0, 0.0<=h<=30.0)
    semantic boundary
    size: Size(270.0, 30.0)
  ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is my flutter doctor:

```
 [✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.19.0-0.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-US)
   • Flutter version 1.19.0-0.0.pre at /Applications/flutter
   • Framework revision a849daf283 (4 days ago), 2020-05-07 18:59:02 -0700
   • Engine revision 3953c3ccd1
   • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-5.0.dev 4da5b40fb6)


 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
   • Android SDK at /Applications/Android/sdk
   • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
   • ANDROID_HOME = /Applications/Android/sdk
   • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
   • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
   • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
   • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
   • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
   • Chrome at /Applications/Google 
     Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
   • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
   • Flutter plugin version 46.0.1-dev.5
   • Dart plugin version 192.7761
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
   • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
   • Flutter extension version 3.8.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
   • iPho • acd5efecf25da9ac75d28 • ios            • iOS 13.4.1
   • Web Server • web-server                               • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
   • Chrome     • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.138

 • No issues found!
```

After I traced the problem, I found that [sizeWithOverflow] in the paint method of the RoundSliderThumbShape is null. But I have no idea how to make it not null since this is flutter's own code.

Moreover, just for the side note, if I remove the SliderTheme everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution. This probably isn't pretty but this is what I can find so far. I am open to better solutions.

1. I create a new class which inherit from SliderComponentShape.
2. In its paint method I comment out `assert(!sizeWithOverflow.isEmpty);`
3. I added `sizeWithOverflow = parentBox.size;`

This works.

So the code looks like this:

```
class SpecialSliderThumbShape extends 
     SliderComponentShape {
    // .... All the same codes as the original RoundSliderThumbShape

 @override
 void paint(
   PaintingContext context,
   Offset center, {
   Animation<double> activationAnimation,
   @required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
   bool isDiscrete,
   TextPainter labelPainter,
   RenderBox parentBox,
   @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
   TextDirection textDirection,
   double value,
   double textScaleFactor,
   Size sizeWithOverflow,
 }) {
   assert(context != null);
   assert(center != null);
   assert(enableAnimation != null);
   assert(sliderTheme != null);
   assert(sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor != null);
   assert(sliderTheme.thumbColor != null);

   // This is the difference here:
   // assert(!sizeWithOverflow.isEmpty);

   sizeWithOverflow = parentBox.size;

   //... Continue same as the original
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. 1.19 came with a change that started showing an error for "null arguments".
I have this too, and we are not the only ones. A nice dude opened a ticket to flutter's team about this.
You are welcome to follow for more updates.

[Flutter: A null value was passed into a non-nullable parameter value This will become a failure when runtime null safety is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708880/flutter-a-null-value-was-passed-into-a-non-nullable-parameter-value-this-will-b/61716353#61716353)